# is it possible to get this texture in cycles?

Tags: texturing

[image]

hello, im newish to blender and want to this texture for something very similar but dont know how. Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

[image]

I did what christopher did but got a different result and dont know why.

Comment: Try a scaled down noise texture with a color ramp.

Comment: The text in your image looks 2D, is that correct? If that's the case, then this will likely not work. What part of the effect are you trying to recreate (What feature are you going for - vertex lighting, emission, outline, etc...)?

Comment: it is 2D im trying to get that texure aw close a possible

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I'm trying to translate the "texture" into 2D (mentally) - obviously some components are 3D dependent (such as the light coming "down" from the edges), so I'm trying to figure out what it is you want to achieve. Is it lighting from the edges? Or is it only one corner? Like where is the pink supposed to go? Also, are you trying to get the "noise" look as well?

Comment: im trying to get pink edge and that "noise/grany" texture. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So I spent a good amount of time studying [the original image by Alec Tear](https://www.instagram.com/p/CH_JlRgBikC/). From what I've gathered from [his website](https://www.alectear.com/selected-artworks) and [behance projects](https://www.behance.net/gallery/107216249/36-Days-of-Type-2020) he uses Illustrator to "handshade" his lettering to get this metallic grainy texture effect. He really knows how to draw light flowing on curved surfaces and I think this is key to get this effect : understanding light.

I tried multiple approaches to attempt to recreate the effect with shaders but **in the end this is what worked best for me : a semi-rough semi-metallic shader with grain and lots of lights and good positioning.** There is probably a better way, but I'm no blender pro. I also added some bloom.

[image: 3d typographie grain texture blender scene - style from Alec Tear]

This is what the final render looks like (Eevee).

[image: 3d typographie grain texture blender render (eevee) - style from Alec Tear]

In my render the darks aren't as dark, the lights not as light because I don't really master lighting and shaders yet. I wasn't able to recreate the light flowing along the edges because I'm pretty sure the shading in the original image is handmade and not generated.

In Alec Tear's work the lighting isn't as real as you would expect, and I think that's what gives it its charm, attractiveness and retro feel.

Hope this helps. I've learned a lot doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this - I know it looks terrible in my example - that's just because I just made a quick mockup and left the default (ugly) topology of the letters intact and so the shading is kind of wacky. The point is to show the node setup - Try it on your objects and see if it works for you. You may need to adjust the ColorRamp sliders until the look is "just right":

[image: Points]

EDIT - here's an example with better topology and smooth shading:

[image: Points2]

Answer (score 0):

In 2d perhaps it would be possible to fake it by using a procedural texture.

I've used a *Voronoi Texture* here.

[image]